# How to add markers in graph using python as shown below?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to design a graph like below, but, I don't know- how to add markers like the one shown in the graph.
Can somebody help me with this?

For plotting a graph, I am using `matplotlib` package in `python`.

[image]

Comment: have you looked into annotations from matplotlib? 
https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pyplots/annotation_basic.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-annotation-basic-py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From matplotlib doc [Annotations](https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html) you can modify the example with the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

t = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01)
s = np.cos(2*np.pi*t)
line, = ax.plot(t, s, lw=2)



ax.plot(2, 1, marker = "v", color='blue', fillstyle='none')
bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="white", ec="black", lw=1.2)
t = ax.annotate('local max\n x = 2, y = 1', xy=(2, 1), xytext=(3, 1.5),
        arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", facecolor='black'), bbox=bbox_props,
        )

ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!!

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Bokeh framework as an alternative to matplotlib. (I personally find it much better.)

```
for plot in [p1, p3, p5]:
        plot.add_tools(HoverTool(
            tooltips=[
                ("(x,y, name)", "($x, $y, $name"),  # use @{ } for field names with spaces
            ],
        formatters={
            'date': 'datetime',  # use 'datetime' formatter for 'date' field
            'adj close': 'printf',  # use 'printf' formatter for 'adj close' field
            # use default 'numeral' formatter for other fields
        },

        # display a tooltip whenever the cursor is vertically in line with a glyph
        # mode='hline'
        mode='mouse'
    ))
```

[image]

Comment: Will try this out!! Thanks!!